# JMeter Error: Unable to access jarfile CMDRunner.jar

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have downloaded "Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool" and "jpgc - Standard Set" from JMeter Plugins Manager.

I am executing below command from Jmeter/lib/ext path as :
Command 1:
java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv C:\jtl\Aggregate_Report.csv --input-jtl C:\jtl\file1.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport -cp "cmdrunner-2.0.jar;JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar"

Command 2:
java -jar C:\Software\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv C:\jtl\Aggregate_Report.csv --input-jtl C:\jtl\file1.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport -cp "cmdrunner-2.0.jar;JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar"

Command 3: 
java -jar C:\Software\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv C:\jtl\Aggregate_Report.csv --input-jtl C:\jtl\file1.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

For above all the 3 commands, error is displayed as 
"Error: Unable to access jarfile CMDRunner.jar"

Kindly provide your suggestions.
JMeter version is 2.13

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Jmeter 3.2` it contains a file in the bin called

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat
```

using the following command worked for me when doing it manually.

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --tool Reporter --generate-csv "AggregateReport.csv" --input-jtl "results.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

When doing it using Jenkins got another error which i am trying to figure out.

> Error details:
>
> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property
>   'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to
>   show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are facing issue with downloading cmdrunner you should download that jar manually from [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar)

put that jar at JMETER-HOME\lib folder and restart jmeter.